# How to get object count in S3 bucket for current date using spring-integration-aws?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp, spring-integration-aws

Have a spring integration application where files are routed from a folder to S3 buckets using s3-outbound-channel-adapter. I need to know the number of files/object that are stored under S3 bucket for today's date(current date) and files having format (csv/txt) alone.

Would like to know how to get it using spring-integration-aws without using aws-sdk directly?

Observed that spring-integration-aws has a method in S3session.

```
@Override
    public S3ObjectSummary[] list(String path) throws IOException {
}
```

Do we need to use comparator on S3ObjectSummary or is there any other method available to achieve this. Any suggestion is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you use `S3Session.listNames()` and then filter result for desired file extensions.

If you really need some more comprehensive logic, you can consider to use a `S3RemoteFileTemplate` and its `executeWithClient()` to access a low-level AWS API.